# SQL | Select (...) where 2 columns combined equal (xy)

Tags: sql, .net, oracle

I have no Idea how i could solve the following problem in an effective way.

**Given**:

1.
A Telephone Number as one single String e.g.: `1111223344`

2.
A Database with this Number `split in 2 different Columns`
(First part of Number in `ColA`, Second Part of Number in `ColB`)
 | The Database is huge (up to 100 GB)

Lets say in ColA is '11112'
and in ColB is '23344' - Combined these 2 Columns are the String we are looking for. We don't know how many characters are in which column.

**Need**: A select Statement, that `combines ColA + ColB and compares it to the given String`. If it Equals: Select the Row.

The selected Row/Rows will be selected and used with a .Net Application.

Comment: Have you tried basic string concatenation? Where ColA + ColB = @StringGiven

Comment: Are the phone numbers always split 5 and 5?

Comment: I'll quote myself: `I have no Idea how i could` - I usually try my best to solve problems myself. But as i said in the Question: I dont even have an idea, how this one could work. Ofc i have ideas how i could solve this within my .net application, but the would be terribly ineffective.

Comment: I should maybe add, that i dont know much SQL. As said in the Post; We dont know how many chars are in which of the columns - can also be 1 / 9 or 2/20.  @ScottChamberlain No, tbh i dont even know what that is :-)

Comment: You say you have no idea but you almost posted the syntax in your question. Try the where clause I posted in my first comment.

Comment: @Luke your first part of your comment answered my question. Can you give us more information about how what columns represent, I find it very weird that a string would just be split randomly across two columns.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ofc its weird. the Data is inserted by Users, which have 2 Textboxes to add the Prefix and the number. Sadly they are messing up alot: sometimes the number fully in the prefix column, sometimes in the numbercolumn itself, sometimes split in both. 

If i posted a syntax close to the correct Querry that was pure luck.

Comment: @TheGameiswar you don't need to post an answer and a comment saying the same thing, posting an answer gives the OP a notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started. You will want to adjust this depending on the actual requirements.

If the two values are guaranteed to be strings:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable m
WHERE m.ColA + m.ColB = '1111223344'
```

If the two values aren't guaranteed to be strings:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable m
WHERE CONCAT(m.ColA, m.ColB) = '1111223344'
```

Comment: Ugh. Why the NOLOCK hint? That is just bad. And if you ARE going to use it, you should at least include the WITH keyword. Omitting it is deprecated.

Comment: Honestly, that is not going to perform very well because I don't think it will use any indexes, and why the NOLOCK?

Comment: @DunningKrugerEffect you should read about and understand what that NOLOCK hint actually does. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I have. It has become habit due to requirements in my organization. I have edited my answer to remove the nolocks.

Comment: If your organization requires that bloody hint on every query you need to sit down with the managers an explain to them what is really happening. I truly hope you guys don't deal with anything where accuracy is important...like with money.

Comment: Asked this in another comment as well but i want you to get the notice as well: What exactly does the NOLOCK statement? Explaned for dummies if possible :-)

Comment: @Luke read this article. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ It can make your queries slightly quicker but it comes at a cost. That cost is accuracy. Many people think it is just dirty reads but it is so much more. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows. If accuracy of the query is important just avoid it. NOLOCK has its place but not everywhere.

Comment: @SeanLange We typically build dashboards for quickly displaying aggregate data that won't be greatly skewed by a few records that may get rolled back. Deadlocks can be a big deal for some of our clients, as they don't want to upgrade their resources to handle additional load just so a few dashboards can be hitting the server all day long. Gotta work with what you're given.

Answer (score 2):

One way i could think of is, to  use Hashbytes as a computed column .you can index this column for good performance as well..

```
CREATE TABLE #TESTMAIN
(
NMBR VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO #TESTMAIN
SELECT '123456'
UNION ALL
SELECT '3456'

create table #backup
(
nmbr1 varchar(10),
nmbr2 varchar(10)
)

insert into #backup
select '123','456'
union all
select '34','56'

Alter table #testmain
add mainnmbr as hashbytes('SHA1',nmbr)

select * from #testmain

Alter table #backup
add bckpnmbr as hashbytes('SHA1',concat(nmbr1,nmbr2))

select * from #testmain
select * from #backup
```

Now you can do a simple compare on data below..
[image]

Comment: Not an option for me, because i only have select permissions on the Database. But a huge thanks for writing that Querry!

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is simply to find the set of rows whose concatenation is xy then you might try this:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(50), @y VARCHAR(50)

SELECT ColA, ColB
FROM Source WITH NOLOCK --If you like, depending on your environment
WHERE ColA = @x AND ColB = @y
```

The NOLOCK business depends on who else is likely to be writing to your database concurrently with your query.  It's great if you have the database to yourself, or if it's strictly intended for read operations.  Not so much if you have mission critical writes which may happen anytime of the day or night.  Of course you will need to size @x and @y appropriately.  If you have an area code an a 7 digit number, without the decoration @x might be VARCHAR(3) and @y might be VARCHAR(7)

Comment: NO the NOLOCK hint is still dangerous if you need accurate results. It is NOT a magic go faster button. It has some very serious implications that all too often get glossed over.

Comment: The implications are that the read uncommitted isolation level is dangerous if you're not in an isolated environment.  But it is still the fastest.  That's the tradeoff that we all consider.  Performance vs. security.  Security is not the overriding concern in every situation.

Comment: I would add that it's not the magic button, but it is absolutely the go faster button.  Serious implications noted.

Comment: It is faster but often not very much. For things like aggregate reporting it is fine. I don't get your point about security. NOLOCK has nothing to do with security at all. It has to do with accuracy. If a result set that is reasonably close most of the time if acceptable than perhaps the slight performance boost is ok. In most OLTP systems this is not acceptable most of the time.

Comment: True that accuracy is more accurate than security.  In my business they're synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more reads than writes you can increase performance by using functional based index ([more info](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/function_based_indexes)) with query suggested by DunningKrugerEffect. If not create that index you will have table full scan, which is not good for big tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable m 
WHERE CONCAT(m.ColA, m.ColB) = '1111223344'
```

Comment: I've got it working, but i had to remove the NOLOCK. Is it due to it beeing Oracle SQL, or due to not having enough DB permissions? 

Could you explain me, what exactly NOLOCK does?

Comment: NOLOCK better described here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/11/theres-something-about-nolock-webcast-video/

Comment: Luke can you share some benchmark, with and without function based index? For read and write and how big your table.